# Enums intersection in prisma schema

Tags: typescript, prisma

Is there a way to merge 2 enums in a prisma schema? I'm talking about something like this

```
enum Enum1 {
  value1,
  value2
}

enum Enum2 {
  value3,
  value4
}

enum Enum3 { // this results in having the values: value1, value2, value3, value4
  ...Enum1,
  ...Enum2
}
```

Basically, I'm looking for something like a typescript intersection, but for prisma enums.

Answer (score 0):

There is now way to merge enums in a Prisma schema. You might want to create a new enum that contains the values of the other enums.

Comment: Please provide code to explain your answer